# Create a permalink for a post's attachments

Tags: permalinks, attachments

I'm trying to create a custom permalink structure. I'd like to have a custom page which displays each post's image attachments, using the following structure:

*www.mysite.com/hello-world/images*

If anyone visited this URL, it would serve up a page of images that are attached to hello-world. It's kind of like having a subpage I guess, but I'd want it for posts (not pages) and I'd want it to be automatic.

I have a template .php coded-up for this purpose; it will grab all attached images and display them. I'm just looking for a way that people can get to it via the above URL structure.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this ie. if there's an easy way in Wordpress, or if I need to look into Rewrite rules in my .htaccess. Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve that by adding a rewrite endpoint via [`add_rewrite_endpoint`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

[This post](http://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/) from a WordPress developer has a good explanation of how they work.